# Let $f,g:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous and $f(x)<g(x)$ for all $x\in [a,b]$, then exists a $\delta >0$ s.t $f+\delta \leq g$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

My attempt.

We know that $f(x)<g(x)$ for all $x\in [a,b]$. We define $h(x)=g(x)-f(x)$, then $h(x)>0$. By the archimedean property exists a $n_{x}$ such that $0<\frac{1}{n_{x}}<h(x)$. Then we choose $n=max\{n_{x}:x\in [a,b]\}$ and define $\delta=\frac{1}{n}$.

We conclude that $f+\delta\leq g$.

Comment: Your proof doesn't work as stated, because first of all, you're taking the maximum of an infinite set (actually an uncountable set). A-priori, this need not exist. Ok, let's say rather than putting maximum, we take the supremum. There's still another issue here, namely that the set might not be bounded above, so the supremum might be infinite (i.e $n=\infty$). So, in this case writing $\delta=\frac{1}{n}$ makes no sense (you can't divide by infinity... said very loosely, this means $\delta=0$). The correct approach is given in the answer below.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I see now where my problem is. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$g-f$ is a continuous map on the compact $[a,b]$. It therefore attains its minimum on that interval at let say $c \in [a,b]$ according to the [extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem?wprov=sfti1). We have for all $x \in [a,b]$

$$g(x)-f(x) \ge g(c)-f(c) \gt0$$

as desired.